# Install PHP 5.2 on Plesk Onyx

Tags: centos7, plesk, php-5.2, plesk-onyx

I have few very old projects build in PHP 5.2. I'd like to install in a Plesk Onyx 17.0.17 server.

CentOS Linux 7

By default, the lower version in this Plesk is 5.4.

Is it possible to install PHP5.2?

Answer (score 0):

Sure. PHP 5.2, while reached end-of-life, is still available in recent Plesk versions (though it is marked as 'outdated' in Plesk Onyx 17.8).

Just execute:

```
# plesk installer --select-release-current --install-component php5.2
```

Here is a great article on how to install additional PHP versions shipped with Plesk - https://support.plesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/115000769793

Moreover, you always can add custom PHP handler and register it in Plesk - https://support.plesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/115000497853